# Deploying Kafka on AWS

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to deploy kafka on aws. While running the kafka server, i am getting the following error :

```
kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to hostname:9092: Cannot assign requested address.
        at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:309)
        at kafka.network.Acceptor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:237)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(SocketServer.scala:108)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(SocketServer.scala:91)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach(MapLike.scala:206)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:91)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:179)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:37)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
        at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:305)
```

Does anybody have idea about this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your `server.properties` file? Did you configure it properly?

Comment: I have just  uncommented the following line in server.properties and changed it as follows :
listeners=PLAINTEXT://<aws-elastic-ip-address>:9092

Comment: If i left it commented then it is running successfully having the endpoint as PLAINTEXT://<aws internal ip.compute-aws.amazon.com>:9092

But the consumer is unable to connect to the kafka broker.

Thats why i change it to elastic ip. but then the kafka broker is not starting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting advertised.listeners to the public elastic ip so the initial bootstrap meta data request will return an ip that the clients can actually connect to.